# Discord.js messageReactionAdd Not firing

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I understand that messageReactionAdd only works with cached messages but even after manually caching them it still wont fire.

Currently my code is:

```
client.once('ready', () => { 
    console.log(config.readymesssage); 
    var channel = client.channels.resolve('761577724379791450');
    channel.messages.fetch({limit: 90}).then((message) => {
        console.log("done")
    })
});

client.on('messageReactionAdd', async(reaction) => {
    console.log("reacted");
});
```

I have tried using raw events I used the code block from [Here](https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/coding-guides/raw-events.md) and I have also tried using partials, neither of which seem to be working. I'm unsure as to what else I cant try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling intents has fixed the issue, they first needed turning on in the developer portal and then I needed to add the following lines,

```
let Intss = new Discord.Intents(Discord.Intents.ALL);

const client = new Discord.Client({ws: { intents: Intss }});
```

Now the event is firing as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Another working solution that is most likely better is

```
const bot = new Discord.Client({ partials: ['USER', 'REACTION', 'MESSAGE'] });
```

Now, you will have to check for partials before doing anything with the data (and fetch the data if it is partial). But this way, you won't have to deal with intents and if your bot scales to 100+ servers, you won't have to wait for verification either.